# Find invalid images in a huge collection

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm in need of a way to detect broken image files in a huge collection (tens of thousands of images). The way I do it now is by using PIL like this:

```
try:
    im = PIL.Image.open(f)
    # image valid
except:
    # image invalid
    ...
```

But that's way too slow. It'd take hours, days to check all files.

Is there a quicker way to find all invalid images in a folder by means of Python?

`imghdr` isn't sufficient unfortunately because it does not detect truncated images.

Comment: It doesn't seem likely that there would be - you have to attempt to open the file to determine if the image data is truncated.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so. But I thought there would be a way with less overhead for decoding and whatever else is done during Image.open

Comment: Some other options: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/46919/is-there-a-tool-to-check-the-file-integrity-of-a-series-of-images

Answer (score 1):

You could speed it up some by wrapping the code from your question up in a function. Then make a list of all filenames to be tested and use `Pool.map` from the `multiprocessing` module to apply the function in parallel to all files using as many cores as your machine has.

If your machine has N cores, this could give you a factor N speedup. In practice it will be less because of `multiprocessing` overhead and maybe I/O bandwidth limits.